# django-eav and south

Tags: python, django, entity-attribute-value, django-south

I'm starting a new django project and as usually i put south on my installed apps.

Then i need some kind of eav to store some fields in a model and i found an app that does exactly what i want, that is django-eav ( https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav )

But now i'm facing a problem, because south complains that doesn't know how to work with django-eav.

```
! Cannot freeze field 'eav.attribute.slug'
! (this field has class eav.fields.EavSlugField)
! Cannot freeze field 'eav.attribute.datatype'
! (this field has class eav.fields.EavDatatypeField)

! South cannot introspect some fields; this is probably because they are custom
! fields. If they worked in 0.6 or below, this is because we have removed the
! models parser (it often broke things).
! To fix this, read http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork
```

I'm reading this http://south.aeracode.org/docs/customfields.html and i'm trying to solve this problem without giving up any of the two projects.

Anyone could help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer I found was from http://south.aeracode.org/docs/settings.html#setting-south-migration-modules

It suggests that you set add a SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES dict in settings.py, and map that app to a nonexistent module

```
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'eav': 'ignore',
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at github it appears that django-eav is not under very active development.  If it's working as you want and you don't expect to change its data model, you don't need to apply South to it.  South works fine managing some apps and not others.

Definitely use South on the apps that you're building and modifying.  But for a stable library, I rarely bother.

Comment: But eav is tight to my model.

Comment: It's decoupled through a GenericForeignKey. As long as the primary keys & names of your models don't change, you have nothing to worry about. You can add and remove fields on your models to your heart's content. If you're renaming your models or changing the PKs in your own models, you'll have to do a fancy data migration that includes the EAV tables. Still possible without South managing the eav app, but tricky. It would be tricky with south managing EAV.

Comment: yes, i agree with you. i haven't added eav and other third party apps. thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I think i found one possible solution.

http://south.aeracode.org/docs/customfields.html#field-name-patterns

Next to my model i put this:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_ignored_fields
add_ignored_fields(["^eav\.fields\.EavDatatypeField"])
add_ignored_fields(["^eav\.fields\.EavSlugField"])
```

now it works.